# How to pass select value by javascript?

Tags: javascript

like this is my form's select box

```
<select name="cutid" onchange="findcustid(this.value)">
<option value="1001">cust 1</option>
<option value="1002">cust 2</option>            
<option value="1003">cust 3</option>            
</select>
```

now i have this ajax code which is passing and fill some select boxes

```
function findcustid(custid) {
    var custid = custid;
}

function Inint_AJAX() {
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {} //IE
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {} //IE
    try {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {} //Native Javascript
    alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
    return null;
};

function dochange(src, val) {
    var req = Inint_AJAX();
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById(src).innerHTML = req.responseText; //retuen value
            }
        }
    };
    req.open("GET", "podetfill.php?data=" + src + "&val=" + val + "&custid=" + custid); //make connection
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=iso-8859-1"); // set Header
    req.send(null); //send value
}
window.onLoad = dochange('proid', -1); // value in first dropdown
```

on this line

```
req.open("GET", "podetfill.php?data="+src+"&val="+val+"&custid="+custid);
```

of above code i've added `+"&custid="+custid` this but its not pass value of `custid` on `podetfill.php` page and getting error

```
Error: custid not defined
```

Comment: custid is locally scoped to the function findcustid (above). To use it, you need to declare var custid outside of the function. ie globally.

Comment: Doesn't your code look a lot better now its been formatted correctly - easier to read too - might even help you solve your problem ... my tip - always indent your code ([Handy HTML / JS beautifier here](http://jsbeautifier.org/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use your method for the following reasons :

- the `var custid` is declared within a function - so its only accessible within that function
- Even if the `var custid` was declared a global you still couldn't use it as the AJAX gets executed using the `window.load` event meaning the `select.change` event wouldnt have been fired yet

One solution would be to get the value of the `select` before using it :

```
var cus = document.getElementById('custid');
var custid = cus.options[cus.selectedIndex].value;
req.open("GET", "podetfill.php?data=" + src + "&val=" + val + "&custid=" + custid); //make connection
```

you also need give the `select` an `id` attribute to use this code :

```
<select id="custid" name="cutid" onchange="findcustid(this.value)">
```

Comment: it seem working but only pass value 0 everytime now passing value of custid like 1001,1002 etc and it's passing value 0 cause default option value is 0 <option value="0"> Select Customer</option>

Comment: @Jaiff you are executing your code using the `window.load` event - it will always send the default value - perhaps you should call this method from the `change` event on the select

Answer (score 1):

Move your declaration of `var custid` outside the function.  It is not visible to the `dochange` function

Comment: when i declare it outside it's not getting error but pass value of custid="undefined"

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, there is fiddle link below.

```
<select name="report_type" onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="1001">cust 1</option>
<option value="1002">cust 2</option>            
<option value="1003">cust 3</option>            
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymutlu/JVrwL/

Comment: i didnt realize the scope problem in question. This is my solution. Btw wht is OP?

Comment: See my answer - explanation of the problem and solution

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is sent when window is loaded(by window.onLoad = dochange('proid', -1);) when you have not yet made a customerid selection, thus it's either undefined or null.

Send your ajax request on your selection instead.

`<select name="cutid" onchange="dochange('proid', -1)" >`

and add following in the beginning of dochange function as ManiseUK said
    `var cus = document.getElementById('custid');` 
    `var custid = cus.options[cus.selectedIndex].value;`

remove
`window.onLoad = dochange('proid', -1);`

Answer (score -1):

```
  <select name="report_type" onchange="findcustid(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
     <option value="1001">cust 1</option>
     <option value="1002">cust 2</option>            
     <option value="1003">cust 3</option>            
  </select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​


  <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript"  >
   function findcustid(custid) {
   var custid = custid;
   //alert(custid);
   }
  </script>
```